# How to make a command run multiple times in same script

Tags: powershell, directory

I have another question that my lack of experience in PowerShell has rendered me stumped. I was wondering if I could adjust my script to allow a command to be run many times from different source-folders.

For example, I would like it to run in C:\temp\test and C:\temp\test2. I have tried wording it to run as *$path= C:\temp\test','C:\temp\test2'* but that just came back with wonky what-if remove results (one folders contents are completely deleted but not the others).

If somebody could just explain how to run this command in multiple different folders within the same script, that would be so very much appreciated because I'm about to pull my hair out over how simple, yet hard it is ;P

Script that works but only has one destination:

```
$path = "C:\temp\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
$keep = 2
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | 
             Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | 
             Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

Script that I tried with multiple folders but had unfavorable results:

```
$path = "C:\temp\test","C:\temp\test2","C:\temp\test3"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
$keep = 2
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | 
             Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | 
             Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adjust you processing slightly to gather and process your files by directory vs all at once.

```
$path = "C:\temp\test","C:\temp\test2","C:\temp\test3"
$keep = 2

ForEach ($Dir in $Path) {

  #*** Get files for current Path, i.e. $Dir ***
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File

  #*** Process the files found ***
  if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
      $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | 
               Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | 
               Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
  }

} #End ForEach
```